# VBA Macro - How to click a link in java web page

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I want to get data from a web page.

web adress:
https://intvrg.gib.gov.tr/intvrg_side/main.jsp?token=d1078f5e3dc646b78d5d4e5842f21e97feb48d366bc7617458b6679dec12675154a01fccc42292bb04d926bc259dbc75e39dd8e202535fd70a7098396c74a6f7

After this page I click "Diger Sorgulamalar" at the right box, then try to click "Vergi Kimlik Numarası Dogrulama"

With vba code after navigating to the web page I can click first link with the code:

```
IE.document.getElementById("gen__1155").Click
```

However, I cannot navigate to the "Vergi Kimlik Numarası Dogrulama". I tried:

```
IE.document.getElementById("H7d190dfed4bed-faf6170603664e").Click
```

But this does not work. The web source code is like below.

[image: websourcecode]

How can I go to that page?

Comment: In what way dos it not work? Does `IE.document.getElementById("H7d190dfed4bed-faf6170603664e")` return anything?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `H7d190dfed4bed-faf6170603664e` does not appear in the HTML code you posted, so it cannot find it. So probably the ID changes everytime the page is accessed so you cannot hardcode the ID.

You need to find something else to determine the correct link. Is the link name `Vergi Kimlik Numarası Dogrulama` always the same?

Then you could loop through all links and check to find the name of the tag:

```
For Each lnk In IE.document.GetElementByTagName("a")
    If lnk.innerHTML = "Vergi Kimlik Numarası Dogrulama" Then
        lnk.Click
        Exit For 'if there is only one link with that name you can exit here.
    End If
Next lnk
```